# Is there a way that I can use a string variable to replace the delimiters in re.split?

Tags: python, string, split

To make my code more readable, I want to use a string variable called `delimiters` to replace `' @\n\t,.;()'` in

```
re.split(r'[ @\n\t,.;()]', line)
```

I have tried with `repr`, like:

```
delimiter = ' @\n\t,.;()'
words = re.split(repr(delimiter), line)
```

but it does not work as I expect. Does anyone know how to make it possible?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. It should be re.split(r'[ @\n\t,.;()]',line)

Comment: Did you look at what `repr(delimiter)` evaluates to? Why did you think that would be the same as the first snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
delimiters = r' @\n\t,.;()'
words = re.split(r'[%s]' % delimiters, line)
```

Regular expression is just a string, which you can construct by interpolation and concatenation. Note that `r` before delimiters string though, without that delimiters will contain newline and tab character instead of literal `\n\t`.